# Squished images in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is a really weird bug. When I load my website in google chrome the first time I view it the images are squished but after I refresh the page it becomes unsquished. This will only happen the first time loading the page.
http://dotacommentaries.com
please load it in google chrome and tell me why the bars are squished.

How do I make these bars unsquished?

http://imageshack.us/f/24/squishedbars.jpg/

Comment: The bars do not unsquish for me after refreshing. Chrome 14, Mac.

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: Because you are using progressive jpeg's ?

Comment: Probably how to prevent this squishing?

Comment: A screenshot showing the problem would help.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a screenshot of what your site should ideally look like. Additionally, you've got some additional alignment issues in Firefox.

Comment: Agreed with thirtydot.  Please post screenshots showing the problem and also showing how it should look.  I viewed it in Chrome on Win 7 and saw no weird rendering.

Comment: What bars?  I see no issues with Chrome on Windows.  Take a screenshot and highlight what you are talking about.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/f/24/squishedbars.jpg/

Comment: i'm using chrome 14 and windows vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 100% width value for the images is screwing it up somehow. Try either removing the width value from this css rule:

```
a.auserbars img {
line-height: 0;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
```

}

or explicitly set it to match the images (310x37).